# Using Bootstrap's model, .modal-header and .modal-footer not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using **Bootstrap 3.3.5**.

I have the a `.modal` with a header, a body and a footer.

According to [Bootstrap Model's example](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#static-example), I am supposed to use the classes `.modal-header`, `.modal-body` and `.modal-footer` for each section of the modal.

I am using the recommended classes but no style is being applied to the divs annotated with `.modal-header` and `.modal-footer`.

I even wrote the styles manually, and still they are not applied.

What is happening here?

```css
.modal-header {
  min-height: 16.43px;
  padding: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
}
.modal-footer {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: right;
  border-top: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="modal" style="display:block;">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="model-header">
        <button type="button" class="close"></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        This is the body
      </div>
      <div class="model-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Should be modAl , not modEl (lower-case of course).

Comment: @SaehunSeanOh Ow! My bad! I swear I inspected the code three times before posting it! I guess I should rest a bit... Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in your HTML, it's mod**a**l-header and mod**a**l-footer not mod**e**l-header and mod**e**l-footer.

```css
.modal-header {
  min-height: 16.43px;
  padding: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
}
.modal-footer {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: right;
  border-top: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="modal" style="display:block;">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close"></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        This is the body
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: woops you were a few sec faster lol

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I missed this! I'm so embarassed

Comment: Wow, excellent eyes ! Answer in few seconds

Comment: I've done a lot of work with Bootstrap and know the common pitfalls.

Comment: @Steve Me too but I hadn't see it ! Congratulations